# How to open a remote url in cordova webview instead of safari?

Tags: cordova

I have a website deployed in cloud, I want to create a cordova project to display the remote url in cordova webview. I tried the following:

```
[_webViewEngine loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://news.163.com"]]];
```

It would display the page in safari, see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2zI7.png).

Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

As i searched through the same topic in stack-overflow i found these , All the questions are similar if not same and have an answer already :
The first link would be quite helpful to you which tells us to use cordova plugin which is **inappbrowser** (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) :

[Open a link in its own phoneGap default webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692098/open-a-link-in-its-own-phonegap-default-webview)

[Cordova - internal hyperlinks always open in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37866341/cordova-internal-hyperlinks-always-open-in-safari)

[PhoneGap: Opening external URL's in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244965/phonegap-opening-external-urls-in-safari)

Hope this answer leads you to the right answer if not solves it.